# Python dictionary inaccessible in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to access dictionary values with keys passed from view to template. Although after hours of search and struggle, I still am unable to predict the reason. Below are the pictures.

post method in views.py

```
    def post(self, request):
        value = request.POST['value']
        if value is '':
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            start_time = time.time()
            obj = CalcClass(value)
            result=obj.calculate()
            end_time = time.time() - start_time
            output={}
            output['result']=result
            output['end_time']=end_time

            return render(request, 'fibohome/home.html', output)
```

template home.html

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    {% if output %}
                        <h3>Output</h3>
                        <h4>{{ output.result }}</h4>


                        <h3>Time required</h3>
                        <h4>{{ output.end_time }}</h4>

                    {% else %}
                        <h3>None</h3>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

front end UI- after submitting with any number, it just shows None. Although I get output in console.
[image]

Hope I've provided enough info. Thanks!

Comment: add key-value pair dict in post, that why it's unaccessible in the template. If you using get request then it's accessible to the template.

Comment: Correct your last line in views.py like this `return render(request, 'fibohome/home.html', {'output': output})`

Comment: @Paandittya this is the correct answer, you should post it

Answer (score 3):

There's no such thing as `output` in what you pass to the template. `output` is just the name that you've given the context dictionary. The template receives the *contents* of that dictionary. So you can do for example `{{ result }}` and `{{ end_time }}` directly.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I tried your way of solving this but unfortunately it didn't work. Although I made it work with help of comment above by @Paandittya . Below is what I did to get the desired.

In views.py
`return render(request, 'fibohome/home.html', {'output':output})`

In template home.html 
`{{ output.result }}`

Comment: Did you remove the `{% if output %}` check?

Comment: No Daniel. if block still exists.

Comment: Well, that's why; as I said, `output` does not exist.

Comment: Yes. It worked your way too! But I'll need the if block. Thanks a lot for your time and suggestion.